# Xamarin Image Assets for Size Classes

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

I am building an universal Xamarin application for iOS. I am working on the launch screen, and trying to use size classes to modify the layout for iPhone and iPad devices. The positioning works correctly, but when I try to set the image assets things go wrong.

I am trying to use the size class feature on the XCAssets file within Xcode to set the correct image I want for the different screen sizes. I have an image set for [any, any] ([*,*]) for the iPhone, and then I have one set for the [regular, regular] ([+, +]) for the iPad.

In Xcode's interface builder I can see the correct image in my launch xib file when switching between the [any, any] and [regular, regular] size classes. However, when I run this in my iPad simulator I do not see any images at all. Note that when I run the app in my iPhone simulator the [any, any] images are picked up correctly. It's only when running on my iPad simulator things go wrong.

I have resorted to using Xcode's tools as I cannot find a way within Xamarin to get images within a single image set for different size classes. I believe the issue I'm running into must be an issue within Xamarin not respecting the properties set in Xcode.

My question is has anyone been able to get this to work on Xamarin, and if so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution. It appears to in fact be a bug within Xamarin and has todo with Xamarin not always updating the XIB files correctly.

Firstly, do not use the size class options inside of the XCAsset file within Xcode. Simply use the Xamarin version of the tool, and set the iPhone and iPad variations of the image set. I used the naming scheme [image_name][@2x|3x].[ext] for iPhone graphics and the scheme [image_name]~ipad[@2x|3x].[ext] for the iPad variants. However, keep in mind that according to the Apple documentation when you use size classes the ~ipad suffix is ignored. I simply use this suffix to make the file names unique between iPhone and iPad.

Second, go ahead and use size classes as you wish, but do not worry about changing the graphic name, and do not worry about the fact that you will not see an image preview when in the [regular, regular] class.

Third, before running the app use the Xamarin clean command at least once, but sometimes it takes a couple of attempts to fully clean the solution.

After theses steps the image assets worked for me for the iPad via [regular, regular] size class. I know it seems hacky, and may not be the "Xamarin" or "Apple" way of doing things, but it works.

Hope this helps someone else not spend two hours of their life dealing with Xamarin's short comings :)